# .emacs file not compiling correctly

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, command-line, org-mode

I am having issues with my ~/.emacs file. I've pasted the contents to my ~/.emacs file which seems pretty generic.

```
;; -*- mode: elisp -*-
;; Disable the splash screen (to enable it agin, replace the t with 0)
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;; Enable transient mark mode
(transient-mark-mode 1)

;; org-mode configuration
;; Enable org-mode
(require 'org)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))

;; don't create backupfiles 
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

However, every time I:

> source ~/.emacs

I receive the following errors. There seems to be a linking issue. However, I am not exactly sure what is going on. I am very new to emacs and programming so any insights would be appreciated.

> -bash: /Users/coltsfan/.emacs: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
>
> -bash: /Users/coltsfan/.emacs: line 1: `;; -*- mode: elisp -*-'

Comment: Uh, where did you get the idea to do that??

Comment: Also, `-*- mode: elisp -*-` needs to be `-*- mode: emacs-lisp -*-` (there is no `elisp-mode`; just `emacs-lisp-mode`). That's a bit of a footnote in this particular instance, but it's something to fix regardless.

Comment: Which version of emacs are you running?, as this approach still works it's recommended to user a more up to date notation like setting config file in ~/.emacs.d/init.el instead of just ~/.emacs.

However, the first line works for me in carbon emacs 24.5.1.

Answer (score 4):

You don't load your `.emacs` file into your shell.  Instead, it is read by the Emacs program when you start it.  You don't need to do anything special; just type `emacs` at the Bash prompt.

If you are trying to load your changes into an already-running Emacs instance, that's trickier.  In practice, C-x C-f `~/.emacs` and manually evaluate the parts you have recently added. (C-x C-e is handy for this.)

(There is no "compilation" here, by the way.  Emacs can compile elisp files, but `.emacs` is conventionally not compiled.)